# The endpoint should return a unique identifier so that API consumers can trace back to the originally uploaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, endpoint, restful-authentication

I am new to Node.js that is why probably this question might sound silly. I am trying to create a restful API that can load a csv file in the same format as a .csv file given and **the endpoint should return a unique identifier so that API consumers can trace back to the originally uploaded file**.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (row) => {
console.log(row);
})
.on('end', () => {
console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
});
```

This is what I have so far. The endpoint code will tell me when the file is processed but how do I get **a unique identifier so that API consumers can trace back to the originally uploaded file?**

Comment: Try the npm package called `uuid`, it's the de-facto method of creating unique identifiers.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid
Then you can use it like this:
```const uniqueIdentifier = require('uuid').v4(); // use unique identifier however you want.
```

Comment: you can just save a mapping from the id to the filename in any kind of storage, say a database. and refer to the map everytime

Comment: I have used the following code
"
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");

fs.createReadStream("Analytics-20201001-20201031.csv")
  .pipe(csv())
  .on("data", (row) => {
    console.log(row);
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    const uniqueIdentifier = require("uuid").v1();
    console.log(uniqueIdentifier);
    console.log("CSV file successfully processed");
  });
"

Comment: @Hafez I am now able to get a unique identifier every time the file is processed. Now I am trying to **have an API endpoint that takes a unique identifier from point #1 and output the
processing status and the results of the processing. For other situations where the
related file is still processing or something like that, reply with the appropriate response.** Any suggestions

Comment: @Jerryc I am trying to do it without storing a mapping into any database. So far the above code has given me the unique identifier everytime the file is processed but how do  I use it to find processing status?

Comment: i think you still need some kinds of storage to record the processing status, if you dont want to add a database, you can choose to use memcache or even a file

Comment: Yes, It makes sense to store the status somewhere. Probably I will store it in a file. Thanks